"ng" не является внутренней или внешней командой. -в командной строке что делать
Ошибка не исправилась с помощью туторов




Добро пожаловать на сайт ru.SO! как задать хороший вопрос => https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример=>
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

ng - почему она вообще должна работать?
